# A global object in a function doesn't exist in globals()

Tags: python-3.x, scope, global

Why objects denoted by "k" and "p" are not globals?

```
my_global = 5


def func1(n=5):

    global my_global, k, p
    k = 10
    p = 15
    return my_global + n + k + p


all_gobals = globals()

print(k in all_gobals)

print(func1())
```

Output:

```
print(k in all_gobals )
NameError: name 'k' is not defined
```

globals() gives me:

```
{'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None,    '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f1649b48c88>, '__spec__': None, '__annotations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__file__': '/home/pawel/PycharmProjects/test/exerc.py', '__cached__': None, 'random': <module 'random' from '/usr/lib/python3.6/random.py'>, 'itertools': <module 'itertools' (built-in)>, 'string': <module 'string' from '/usr/lib/python3.6/string.py'>, 'a': 20, 'is_perfect_number': <function is_perfect_number at 0x7f1649b7ae18>, 'is_palindrome': <function is_palindrome at 0x7f16497e31e0>, 'ask_for_help': <function ask_for_help at 0x7f16486a5bf8>, 'method': <function method at   0x7f16486a5c80>, 'my_global': 5, 'func1': <function func1 at 0x7f16486a5d08>,     'all_gobals': {...}}
```

Why executing print(k) gives?:

```
NameError: name 'k' is not defined
```

The object 'k' was defined as global, why I cannot use it outisde of the function? 
I saw the following topic and it should wokrs:
[Use of "global" keyword in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`k` isn't defined until the function is called. What would the value of `k` be before the call to `func1`?

Move the call to `func1` above your attempt to use `k` so it's defined before you try to use it.

This is a great example of why (ab)using globals isn't a good idea. It would be much better to return the value from `func1` directly, then use it at the call site. That way it's clear where the data is coming from, and you don't accidentally use data before its defined.

Comment: Thanks, now it makes sense. I use 'global' in many ways becasue I'm learning the concept and I want to understand how it works.

Comment: @kviatek While that's good, I'd *strongly* recommend, once you starting writing real code, to never touch it until you're out of other options. It's entirely possible to write all code without ever using `global`, and most of the time code that doesn't use global will be easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: I'll take your advise. Thanks once more.